# Choosing A Node Item in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to build a quote generator, and I'm trying to take the quotes from a collection of HTML paragraphs.

When I try to access a random item of the list of nodes, I get all of the nodes as a bunch of paragraphs instead of only one paragraphs.

This is my attempted randomizer:

```
const quotes = quotesdocument.querySelectorAll("p");

const randomize = function() {
  for(quote of quotes) {
    let num = (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(quotes.length)) - 1);
    console.log(quotes.item(num));
  }
}
```

And this is and excerpt of the HTML I'm trying to randomize:

```
<p>&#8220;<a href="https://theunboundedspirit.com/ananda-coomaraswamy-quotes/">Art</a> is the supreme task and the truly metaphysical activity in this life.&#8221;</p>
<p>&#8220;Underneath this reality in which we live and have our being, another and altogether different reality lies concealed.&#8221;</p>
<p>&#8220;We obtain the concept, as we do the form, by overlooking what is individual and actual; whereas nature is acquainted with no forms and no concepts, and likewise with no species, but only with an X which remains inaccessible and undefinable for us.&#8221;</p>
<p>&#8220;Everything which distinguishes man from the animals depends upon this ability to volatilize perceptual metaphors in a schema, and thus to dissolve an image into a concept.&#8221;</p>
<p>&#8220;Our destiny exercises its influence over us even when, as yet, we have not learned its nature: it is our future that lays down the law of our today.&#8221;</p>
```

I expected to get only one of these paragraphs, but I keep getting all of them.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just remove the `for` loop? (and probably the `-1` else the index will sometimes be -1)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because you're iterating through all the quotes. Removing the `for` loop, and changing your randomisation logic, would fix this:

```js
const quotes = document.querySelectorAll("p");

const randomize = function() {
  let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length) - 1;
  console.log(quotes.item(num).innerText);
}

randomize();
```

```html
<p>&#8220;<a href="https://theunboundedspirit.com/ananda-coomaraswamy-quotes/">Art</a> is the supreme task and the truly metaphysical activity in this life.&#8221;</p>
<p>&#8220;Underneath this reality in which we live and have our being, another and altogether different reality lies concealed.&#8221;</p>
<p>&#8220;We obtain the concept, as we do the form, by overlooking what is individual and actual; whereas nature is acquainted with no forms and no concepts, and likewise with no species, but only with an X which remains inaccessible and undefinable for
  us.&#8221;</p>
<p>&#8220;Everything which distinguishes man from the animals depends upon this ability to volatilize perceptual metaphors in a schema, and thus to dissolve an image into a concept.&#8221;</p>
<p>&#8220;Our destiny exercises its influence over us even when, as yet, we have not learned its nature: it is our future that lays down the law of our today.&#8221;</p>
```

In the above snippet, I'm `console.log()`ing the *text* inside the element so you can see it works, but to access the element itself, just remove the `innerText` I placed there.

Answer (score 0):

The `for..of` loop you have in your code isn't needed. Just use the code you already have and `num` as the `quotes` array index value. I added button to demonstrate how the function will only return a single value:

```js
function randomQuote() {
  const quotes = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  const num = (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(quotes.length)));
  return quotes[num].innerText;
}

document.querySelector('#buttonEl').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#quoteEl').innerHTML = randomQuote();
});
```

```css
#quoteEl {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="buttonEl" type="button" value="Click for a random quote from the list below" />
<div id="quoteEl"></div>
<p>&#8220;<a href="https://theunboundedspirit.com/ananda-coomaraswamy-quotes/">Art</a> is the supreme task and the truly metaphysical activity in this life.&#8221;</p>
<p>&#8220;Underneath this reality in which we live and have our being, another and altogether different reality lies concealed.&#8221;</p>
<p>&#8220;We obtain the concept, as we do the form, by overlooking what is individual and actual; whereas nature is acquainted with no forms and no concepts, and likewise with no species, but only with an X which remains inaccessible and undefinable for
  us.&#8221;
</p>
<p>&#8220;Everything which distinguishes man from the animals depends upon this ability to volatilize perceptual metaphors in a schema, and thus to dissolve an image into a concept.&#8221;</p>
<p>&#8220;Our destiny exercises its influence over us even when, as yet, we have not learned its nature: it is our future that lays down the law of our today.&#8221;</p>
```